# I try to assign integer number to anonymous type in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

make error :

Error   CS1061  'IQueryable<>' does not contain a definition for 'Matourquntity' and no accessible extension method 'Matourquntity' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: var ds = _context.Matours
                .Where(x => x.BakeryInfoId == BakeryInfoId)
                 .Select(x => new {
                     Matourquntity = x.DieselNeeded 
                    });
            quntity = ds.Matourquntity; this my code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var ds = _context.Matours.Where(x => x.BakeryInfoId == BakeryInfoId).Select(x => new { Matourquntity = x.DieselNeeded }).FirstOrDefault(); 

var quntity =  ds == null ? 0 : ds.Matourquntity;
```

or maybe

```
var ds = _context.Matours.Where(x => x.BakeryInfoId == BakeryInfoId).FirstOrDefault(); 

var quntity =  ds == null ? 0 : ds.Matourquntity;
```

Comment: This work for me thanks